# Magento checkout slooooow

Tags: performance, magento, checkout, freeze

I've got a huge problem with my Magento webshop. It runs good except for the last step when placing a new order.
Especially if the customer wants to order lots of products.

Each product adds ~5 seconds to the checkout process (after the customer pushed the Place Order button).

A lot of customers orders 20+ products at a time so this is a huge problem for us.

The site is hosted at Properhost.net.

Nothing seems to help, is there anyone with some kind of solution here?

Comment: Do you have any extensions or integrations that would modify that part of the checkout process? Data being sent to external sites, for instance.

Comment: such performance issues are rather tied to your web-server ability to perform mysql transactions fast. You should check your mysql settings and slow query logs

Comment: You may also want to checkout the magento db repair tool just incase for whatever reason your tables have not had the correct indexes setup for them. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool

Comment: On the final submit button going slow to return to the success page, another issue is with SMTP servers that are slow to respond but do so within the timeout limit. Of course if it's truly timing out, your customers don't get their emails.

Answer (score 5):

<s>this is indeed *kind of a solution* here, as it involves editing core xml files (it's my understanding there is no way to override those files by a custom module: someone please correct me if I'm wrong), but here it is.</s>
See edit.
Acording to [these guys](http://kassner.com.br/2011/01/magento-slow/) (I haven't try it myself) there are 3 observers that add a lot of execution time in order process. Their solution is to remove/comment those lines:
In **app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/etc/config.xml**:

```
<sales_order_item_save_after>
    <observers>
        <downloadable_observer>
            <class>downloadable/observer</class>
            <method>saveDownloadableOrderItem</method>
        </downloadable_observer>
    </observers>
</sales_order_item_save_after>
```

And in **app/code/core/Mage/Rss/etc/config.xml**:

```
<sales_order_item_save_after>
    <observers>
        <notifystock>
            <class>rss/observer</class>
            <method>salesOrderItemSaveAfterNotifyStock</method>
        </notifystock>
    </observers>
</sales_order_item_save_after>
<sales_order_item_save_after>
    <observers>
        <ordernew>
            <class>rss/observer</class>
            <method>salesOrderItemSaveAfterOrderNew</method>
        </ordernew>
    </observers>
</sales_order_item_save_after>
```

Maybe you can check if you can go without them and give a try. Remember that at next upgrade those changes will probably be lost.
Hope That Helps
**Edit:** At [inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-disable-magento-event/) they found a solution to disabled events without editing core files, it won't be difficult to apply it in this case.

Comment: This had the best speedup effect for me. Time in cart showed a hockey stick with the knee at about 12-15 items. What Magento doesn't need to observe, Magento doesn't need to know. We don't do downloadables so that was the first to go.

Comment: we have the exact same speed issue. No idea what to do. Tried everything